# Dropdown menu width by content

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown menu, which I want change, that the dropdown menu width will be by content. I want to change, that dropdown `<li>` will be in only one row under main `<li>` next to each other.

I have it on jsfiddle here, where I have sass which I use. http://jsfiddle.net/hhkrp71f/3/

Here is my solution:

```css
.header__links {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.header__links nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header__links nav ul li {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: italic;
  color: red;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
.header__links nav ul li a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.header__links nav ul li a:hover {
  color: red;
  transition: color 0.7s ease;
}
.header__links nav ul li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
.header__links nav ul li ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: 500ms ease;
  transition: 500ms ease;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
}
.header__links nav ul li ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__links">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Test Test Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Test Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Test Test Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Test Test</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want to put each and every link in a single line?

Comment: No, next to each other in one row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `right: 0` to your inner `ul`.

```css
.header__links {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.header__links nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header__links nav ul li {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: italic;
  color: red;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
.header__links nav ul li a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.header__links nav ul li a:hover {
  color: red;
  transition: color 0.7s ease;
}
.header__links nav ul li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
.header__links nav ul li ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: 500ms ease;
  transition: 500ms ease;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  right: 0;
}
.header__links nav ul li ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__links">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Test Test Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Test Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Test Test Test</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Test Test</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem! Be sure to accept the answer if it fixed your problem :)

Comment: I will do that, but now I can't :)